# Android 6.x Intent Filter Issues with App Association

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I'm developing a Cordova Phonegap app using the Intel XDK, and modifying the AndroidManifest.xml file to include an intent-filter that captures http and https traffic to example.com and redirects it to my app.

I was updating my intent filter, and I noticed the old filter wasn't working properly in Android 6.0.1.

It had been working in older versions of Android 5.x.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="example.com" 
            android:pathPrefix="" />
    <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.example.com" 
            android:pathPrefix="" />
    <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="example.com" 
            android:pathPrefix="" />
    <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="www.example.com" 
            android:pathPrefix="" />
```

When visiting "http://example.com" I am no longer prompted to associate that url with the App, however, https://example.com does ask for the association, and once that association happens, then both http and https traffic are directed to the app.

The issue is that the prompt is not appearing when I use http.

Here are two variations of filters I tried, with the same issue (these include my updated functionality).

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*example.com" path="" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*example.com" path="/" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*example.com" path="/app" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*example.com" path="" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*example.com" path="/" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*example.com" path="/app" />
</intent-filter>
```

And...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*example.com" path="" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*example.com" path="/" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*example.com" path="/app" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*example.com" path="" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*example.com" path="/" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*example.com" path="/app" />
</intent-filter>
```

These both have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

I tried using a different format, and this filter solved the problem.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data   
            android:scheme="http"
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="*example.com"
            android:path=""
            android:path="/"
            android:pathPrefix="/app" 
        />
</intent-filter>
```

It's not clear to me why the previous filters did not work, it seems like a bug in Android.

I also wrote a simple cordova plugin for this intent-filter, if anyone is interested.

https://github.com/KeithTurkowski/cordova-plugin-simple-android-url-intent-filter

Comment: Hi! I'm having a similar issue. In the <data> I see that you have duplicated attributes. Did that compile for you? In my case it marks an error because scheme and path are duplicated.

Comment: Works fine for me, building with the Intel XDK. And it performs as expected, you might need to update whatever build process you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the response!